# How do I convert a FAT32 to ext3 (keeping the data on it)

Tags: ext3, fat32

Is there a way to convert a FAT partition to ext3 (or other ext..) while keeping the data on it? I don't have access to a external USB hard disk to temporarily store the data, so I'd like to just convert it while the data sits on the partition. Is that possible?

Comment: How big is your disk and how much data is there on it? I have an idea, but it requires you having enough space to store a copy of everything you wish to preserve.

Comment: It is possible if you have at least as much free space as your largest file + the minimum size used by ext3 for FS headers & metadata.  But doing it like that is not really safe if you don't have backups (which you obviously don't have) and depending on the free space available it might take a lot of time and manual work.

Comment: Just assume my hard disk is 90% full. I can't copy the whole partition to a temporary filesystem. I think I will have to buy an extern hdd.

Answer (score 9):

If you're not booting off the partition (is this even possible without using wubi?) and it's at least half free then just use gparted (paste apt:gparted in firefox).

- Run it from the menu.
- Find out the name of your partition
  using `fdisk -l` in a terminal. The
  partition named something like
  /dev/sda* where * is a number. Or look through the list in the upper right edge of gparted
- Resize the fat32 partition to less then half of it's original size
- Create a new ext* partition
- Move all files over to the ext partition
- Delete the old one and resize the ext partition.

Note that I've done this several times and it always worked as intended HOWEVER there are many reports of people that lost data this way. Depending on the amount of data you can use Ubuntu One or Dropbox to backup your stuff. They both offer 2 GB which is most probably not enough.

Comment: Hey, I used gparted to resize and move the partitions around. Now I just have to convert the filesystem. Apparently it's not possible to change a filesystem /with data on it/ without tricks?

Comment: You already split the partition have created ext and moved your files over? Then you can just delete the old fat one and resize ext. No converting needed here.

Answer (score 4):

Direct conversion is not possible. You will need to copy the data to another drive/partition, change the filesystem, then copy the data back.

Answer (score 3):

It is posible to convert.

- FAT32 --> NTFS: see "[Convert FAT32 partition to NTFS without data loss?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303091/convert-fat32-partition-to-ntfs-without-data-loss)"
- NTFS --> ext: use `anyconvertfs`, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/237927).

However, by definition, any conversion is risky, and the only way to guarantee you will "keep the data" is to do a back-up... but in that case it's simpler to delete partition -> create partition -> copy as per the other aanswers.

Comment: it seems `anyconvertfs` can also convert from FAT32 to ext3 directly

Comment: The question asks for FAT32 to ext3, not to NTFS.

Comment: @fosslinux You're missing the points of the question and of the answer. An indirect conversion is possible and deserves to be listed/available for the end user to make their own choice, as long as they are aware of the inherent risks.