# How to change a HDD NTFS partition into a ext4 partition without to loss any?

Tags: partitioning

Can we change a HDD NTFS partition into a ext4 partition, without to loss any?

How?

Greetings & Blessings from Chile!

Juan

Comment: There is no known way to change ntfs to ext4.

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/63022/convert-filesystem-ntfs-ext4

Comment: @mikewhatever you can from NTFS to EXT3 to EXT4 though ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert your NTFS partition on-the-fly to ext4 (or any other) without data loss due to the fact you have to destroy the existing partition to create a new one.

**What you can do:**

- Backup your data to an another drive/partition.
- Reformat the original drive/partition
- Move back your data

That's all.

Or there is an another option but I do not recommend it!

- Use [anyconvertfs](http://anyfs-tools.sourceforge.net/man8/anyconvertfs.8.html) from anyfs-tools to convert ntfs to ext2/3
- Then you can convert it to ext4 using [tune2fs](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs).

Comment: “partition table[s]” are entirely unrelated to the conversion of file systems.