# change partition ntfs to ext4 with out formatting

Tags: partitioning

how to change partition ntfs to ext4 with out formatting ?
my linux all  partition automatically moving ext4 to Ntfs.how i change it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change ntfs to ext4 without formatting or losing all data.
Originally answered [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027308/how-can-i-convert-a-drive-from-ext4-to-ntfs-without-losing-the-data)

> my linux all partition automatically moving ext4 to Ntfs.

What do you mean by that ?