# Can't write files in a partition

Tags: partitioning

I've just installed Ubuntu latest one today (21.04). I don't have any other OS on my laptop, only Ubuntu. I want to edit a text file stored in Part4, which is in NTFS filesystem. But when I edited it I saw that I can't save that as it's showing that the file is in read only. Also I can't delete files from the partition as they return the same issue. What should I do?

Note that I am completely new in Ubuntu, in fact I had windows 10 installed on my laptop till last night when I decided to try something new.

Comment: If your NTFS partition isn't clean (ie. used by a hibernated/fastboot-enabled system), the mount can only be RO so as to prevent data loss.  You've not said how you mounted (I'll assume RW) as a *fs* (file-system) flipping to RO is a sign of a problem being detected & the RO prevents data-loss.  Look at how mounted, or when it *flipped* to RO if it was mounted RW.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to check that-- the mounting system??

Comment: I can't know how you mounted it, if you used the `mount` command it'll be by that command, if you used a GUI tool the message may only be found in logs (or an indicator on the screen/gui). The command `dmesg` will show most logs since boot; though if you know when you mounted it; you can search `journalctl` which for messages around the time/date of your mount.  One benefit of commands, is the messages appear both in logs (if needed later) & appear on screen after your command; if you're using a GUI they are in logs only often (you didn't say if 21.04 desktop, or 21.04 server..)

Comment: You may need to consider [convert NTFS > EXT4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63022/convert-filesystem-ntfs-ext4) but backup everything important!

Comment: @guiverc its desktop version 
I went to Disk and found that its showing for the partition: NTFS-- mounted at /media/usename/Part4

Comment: @24601 that'll be a huge problem, as I have 96 gb free out of 251 gb in that partition...

Comment: Oh another thing, I tried chmod command and it just says that changing permission: read-only

I used this: chmod a+rwx /media/username/Part4 -R

Comment: Finally I got a solution!!! I used ntfsfix command it went so smoothly!! Yayy!! Thanks to both of you for helping me! :D

Comment: You're now strongly advised - again- to use EXT4 instead of NTFS. There WILL come a time when you find errors that can't be corrected with Linux tools (NTFS is a Microsoft proprietary file system) and that will be a problem because you no longer have Windows. Please proceeed accordingly ASAP, for your own good.

Comment: @ChanganAuto ok I'll try to do so... Thanks :D

Comment: I've successfully changed the filesystem to ext4 for all of my partitions. The shrink-&-go method was really helpful. Thanks people! :D