# Convert FAT32 partition to NTFS without data loss

Tags: ntfs, partitioning, fat32, format-conversion

Is there a way to change the partition format from FAT32 to NTFS without losing data in it?

For now I am aware of one method: split partition in two, set the new partition format to NTFS, copy data to it, then delete the old partition and add its space to the new one. One fault with this method is simple: it can't be done if more than a half of the current partition is already used.

So I'm looking for a solution that wouldn't delete my data, and just change the partition format from FAT32 to NTFS. Is something like that possible or not?

Comment: What Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a FAT32 to ext3 (keeping the data on it)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14165/how-do-i-convert-a-fat32-to-ext3-keeping-the-data-on-it)

Comment: @Rinzwind This has nothing to do with ext3...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rinzwind stated,

> it is not possible unless you use Windows.

Now that being said, even if you have windows, you have to be careful when doing it.

You have to move the drive to another machine in order to be able to accomplish that, since you can't convert a live volume.

The command to use to do the conversion is:

```
convert <drive_letter>: /FS:NTFS
```

**Note: Always keep in mind that when dealing with anything to do with partitions, make sure that you have a current backup, in case something goes wrong.**

Comment: Is it possible to run convert.exe on wine?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I don't is possible.

Comment: What about ReactOS?

Answer (score 2):

first go to the drive in windows (I am going to use Z as my drive letter) cmd.exe

`z:`

then return

```
chkdsk /f
```

then return

then do a convert of the drive

```
convert z: /FS:NTFS
```

again return

you will have to allow the unmounting of the drive during those processes.